# iPhone:Issue in NSdecimalNumber conversion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, sqlite, automatic-ref-counting

This is my code:

```
- (void) addOrder {

    if(addStmt == nil) {

        const char *sql = "insert into item(menuid,itemName,price,quantity,spiciness) Values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

        if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sql, -1, &addStmt, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
            NSAssert1(0, @"Error while creating add statement. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    }

    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 1, [menuID integerValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 2, [itemName UTF8String], -1, SQLITE_TRANSIENT);
    sqlite3_bind_double(addStmt, 3, price );
    sqlite3_bind_int(addStmt, 4, [quantity integerValue]);
    sqlite3_bind_text(addStmt, 5, [spiciness UTF8String],-1,SQLITE_TRANSIENT);


    if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(addStmt))
        NSAssert1(0, @"Error while inserting data. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
    else


        menuID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);

    //Reset the add statement.
    sqlite3_reset(addStmt);
}
```

My menuID is NSdecimalNumber.In the else portion

`menuID = sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database);`

I got error as

"`Implicit conversion of sqlite3_int64 to NsdecimalNumber is disallowed with ARC.`

How could I remove this error?Please help..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said that menuID is NSDecimalNumber than It should be like,

```
menuID = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithInt:sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];
```

Answer (score 1):

As it appears to be a 64 bit int, and iOS is a 32 bit system, you might want to use:

```
menuID = [NSDecimalNumber numberWithLongLong:sqlite3_last_insert_rowid(database)];
```